# Environment variables in C#

Tags: c#

I was using an environment variable which was named ABC and had a value of C:/ABC.
In my code I used @"%ABC%/file.txt" for the file path where I had created a folder on the C drive called ABC containing a file called file.txt.

However this does not recognise the environment variable.

Is there any way to make this short-cut work or do I need to manually read the System Environment variable into a separate Environment variable using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` Method (String) within Visual Studio?

Comment: Are you saying you expect the C# compiler to know `%ABC%` relates to a PATH variable and should substitute the value for you?

Comment: Yes I was expecting it to read the System Environment variable that I had set.

Comment: I guess from the below answers you can see that is not the case. Personally I'd find that really odd behaviour.

Comment: Thanks anyway! I now understand how Environment variables work! Previously I was using two lines of code to do what you guys have suggested in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%ABC%/file.txt");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is an aptly named [Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) that should do the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx):

```
string expanded = Enviroment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `System.Environment class`.

```
System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("")
```

Comment: OP said he don't want to use this method ;]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 string _yourpath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%ABC%/file.txt");
```